# Using componentDidUpdate to change the state in the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I have two components placed in a container. One is calling the `Id` of a publication and the other is calling a date of an issue from that specific `publicationId`.

When i called an `Id` for example the `100` then it will also load the issues from that `Id`. After that i can also filter on `issueDate`. But when i change the component with the `Id` again to have other list of issues then it won't rerender the component with the issues.

I heard that this problem is solved when using `componentDidMount` but i don't know what to do after this step:

```
 public componentDidUpdate(): void {
    const{ data, date } = this.state
    if (this.state.data !== data) {

//don't know what to do in this if statement

}
```

This is the code to get publication `Id` with axios:

```
 constructor(props: TTestProductionProgressStatus) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: null,
      data: undefined,
      prodItem: []
    };
  }

  public componentDidMount(): void {
    const urlDate = this.props.location.pathname.split("/")[3];
    const date = urlDate
      ? new Date(
          `${urlDate.substr(0, 4)}-${urlDate.substr(4, 2)}-${urlDate.substr(
            6,
            2
          )}T00:00:00.000+01:00`
        )
      : null;
    axios
      .get<Definitions.ProductionProgressStatus[]>(
        "http://app30:665/v1/productionProgressStatus/crud?publicationId=" +
          this.props.id
      )
      .then(res => {
        this.setState(
          {
            data: res.data
          },
          () => this.handleDateChange(date)
        );
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for making my question more readable. I'm new to stack, but having someone taking their time is appreciative.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to address is that your comparison is incorrect:

```
const{ data, date } = this.state
if (this.state.data !== data) {
```

Here you're comparing `this.state.data` with `this.state.data`; you're just extracting it two different ways, but it's the same properties you're comparing. The way to compare old versus new state is via [the parameters passed to `componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.state.data !== prevState.data) {
```

As to what you do in the if statement, you're probably wanting to make some kind of call to `setState`, which will cause another update. Generally it's better to avoid cascading updates when possible so you don't provoke two different re-renders unnecessarily; in other words, if you find an opportunity to change things without using `componentDidUpdate`, that would be better.